# How to get vbscript variables in sikuli?

Tags: python, vbscript, sikuli

I am sending excel data to sikuli using excel macro when clicking on a button in excel.I am using vbscript shell command to run the sikuli script by sending parameters like

```
rep = Shell("C:\Sikuli\Sikuli-IDE.exe -r C:\iP4-Projects\sikuliExamples\test.sikuli" & RCount & " " & CCount)
```

But i dont know how to get these two parameters in sikuli .please help me if any one knows the syntax to get vbscript variables in sikuli or in python.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the --args flag

`rep = Shell("C:\Sikuli\Sikuli-IDE.exe -r C:\iP4-Projects\sikuliExamples\test.sikuli --args " & RCount & " " & CCount)`

And in the script you can read them in the `argv` array

```
import sys

for a in sys.argv:
    print a
```

But this **may not work** due to a Sikuli bug.
https://answers.launchpad.net/sikuli/+question/194353
https://answers.launchpad.net/sikuli/+question/167400
https://answers.launchpad.net/sikuli/+question/195612